# Why map[time.Time]string doesn't work sometimes?

Tags: datetime, go, associative-array

This is an example to show when map[time.Time]string "doesn't work".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyDate time.Time

func NewMyDate(year, month, day int, tz time.Location) (MyDate, error) {
    return MyDate(time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, &tz)), nil
}

func (md MyDate)ToTime() time.Time {
    return time.Time(md)
}

func main()  {
    timeMap := make(map[time.Time]string)

    md1, _ := NewMyDate(2019, 1, 1, *time.UTC)
    md2, _ := NewMyDate(2019, 1, 1, *time.UTC)

    timeMap[md1.ToTime()] = "1"
    timeMap[md2.ToTime()] = "2"

    for k, v := range timeMap {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

The output:

2019-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 1

2019-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2

Comment: While the answer below may work in this particular case, I would suggest never using a `time.Time` as a map key. `time.Time` is not reliably comparable for equality when generated from the system clock, because it contains a private monotonic clock value to adjust for skew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> func NewMyDate(year, month, day int, tz time.Location) (MyDate, error) {
>   return MyDate(time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, &tz)), nil
> }
> ```

---

`&tz` refers to the address of the `NewMyDate` parameter, which may be different for each call. In Go, function arguments are passed by value.

Use the same time zone for each call. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type MyDate time.Time

func NewMyDate(year, month, day int, tz *time.Location) (MyDate, error) {
    return MyDate(time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, tz)), nil
}

func (md MyDate) ToTime() time.Time {
    return time.Time(md)
}

func main() {
    timeMap := make(map[time.Time]string)

    md1, _ := NewMyDate(2019, 1, 1, time.UTC)
    md2, _ := NewMyDate(2019, 1, 1, time.UTC)

    timeMap[md1.ToTime()] = "1"
    timeMap[md2.ToTime()] = "2"

    for k, v := range timeMap {
        fmt.Println(k, v)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/M10Xn4jsoKS

Output:

```
2019-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your timezone pointer is different every time. Fix this by providing the pointer explicitly:

```
func NewMyDate(year, month, day int, tz *time.Location) (MyDate, error) {
    return MyDate(time.Date(year, time.Month(month), day, 0, 0, 0, 0, tz)), nil
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/M10Xn4jsoKS.

Answer (score 0):

Tha map works as expected, however, your keys are not equal. 
If you add `fmt.Println(md1.ToTime() == md2.ToTime())` you will see that.

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types):

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice. If the key type is an interface type, these comparison operators must be defined for the dynamic key values; failure will cause a run-time panic.